# How to handle command line arguments in TCL

Tags: tcl, command-line-arguments

I am writing a TCL scripts which expects command line arguments. Say the name of my script is myTcl.tcl , and in this case , invoking script with the command line arguments will look something like :

```
./myTcl.tcl -optA optA_arg1 optA_arg2 -optB -optC
```

How can I handle these in TCL ?(Is there any TCL equivalent of *getopts* from bash and if not , then how can it be done)

Thanks

Comment: "typical" arg parsing packages will allow only one argument for an option. You'll either have to write your own, or place the multiple arguments in quotes for calling your program and then split the argument in Tcl.

Answer (score 1):

There are several getopt-like implementations available. I prefer [the one I wrote](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/alternative+getopt). There's also the [cmdline command in tcllib](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.md) and other options you can find on the [Tcl wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/search).